# Mantle mount installation

Tags: wood, brick, mount

Good morning, I have a mantle mount that I would like to install over the fire place, currently, I have wood paneling over the brick, I want to install to the wood, but I cant seem to locate,
the studs, the brick seems to be approx 4 to 5 inches behind, any ideas on the proper way to install without, poking a bunch of holes to search? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can add some pictures?

Comment: I'll try when I get home, but I know there is brick approx 4 inches behind the paneling.

Comment: Please [merge your guest and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!